# Gradient Lines between GridView

Tags: android, gridview, shapes

I want a line like below image between gridview:
[image]

Following i have been tried.

GridView XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridhouseindex"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:listSelector="@null"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:verticalSpacing="22dp">
</GridView>
```

Adapter XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgViewHouseIndex"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/univer" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtViewHouseIndex"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

   <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/grid_line" />
</LinearLayout>

   <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/grid_line" />
```

Grid Line XML:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#b6a9a9" />

<gradient
    android:angle="90"
    android:endColor="#b6a9a9"
    android:startColor="#FFFFFF" />

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="1dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="1dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="1dp"
    android:topRightRadius="1dp" />
```

By using the above code, i am getting like following image:

[image]

Can someone please tell me, where i am going wrong or what i have to do to get the exact output.

**Updated:**
This is the output i am getting.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `Horizontal` Lines: `gradientbackground.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:dither="true"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <gradient
        android:angle="180"
        android:centerColor="#000000"
        android:endColor="#F6F6F6"
        android:startColor="#F6F6F6" />
</shape>
```

`Layout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroll_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:splitMotionEvents="false" >
    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/backgrad" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

For `Vertical` Lines: `gradientbackground.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:dither="true"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:centerColor="#000000"
        android:endColor="#F6F6F6"
        android:startColor="#F6F6F6" />
</shape>
```

`Layout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroll_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:splitMotionEvents="false" >
    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/backgrad" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope this can help you out.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Nearly i got the destination. But i didn't get the exact output. I will update the question and add the image. Please refer my question.

Comment: @AbdulRahman You can get reference from `@RomanGuy's` Code : https://code.google.com/p/shelves/ for divider.

Comment: Thank You for the link, i will follow up that project.

Comment: @Abhan What is the drawble backgrad here and where should i use these layouts for the grid view

Comment: @AbdulRahman Did u get any solution for this. i have the same requirement. if u r done please help me.

Comment: @AndroidDev I think with this answer you can able to get that or follow that code google link, sorry i don't have the running code for that.